# How to replace color for colored objects in image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I am trying to detect edges in images of a video, but edge detection methods such as canny does not work very well might be due to in similarity between boxes's color and floor color or brightness so I want to find a way to make all red and blue boxes look as white as possible, or may be the best way to detect edges as perfect as possible for every frame since that is the ultimate goal.

[image]

Comment: If it is blue/red to white, why not use inRanges and HSV color space?

Comment: What's the output you are getting?

Comment: @api55 well I tried to use cv2.inrange but I guess I don't know exactly how as it didn't work for me, could you please provide a code sample to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you using color tracking then.

1. Convert to HSV

cv2.bgr2hsv

Why hsv? eventhough the brightness change, u can still detect that color

2. Filtering

You can use cv2.inrange

3. Noise cancelling

Use cv2.Gaussianblur

4. Contouring

use cv2.findContours

5. Find the edge
   use ur method

Repeat this step for every color of your box

Hope this help

Comment: thnx, but I don't exactly how to implement the inrange function, coud you provide a small code to do that?

Comment: say that you already convert the image into HSV colorspace with variable name frame1. thresh = cv2.inRange (frame1, lowerlimit, upperlimit). It will change your image into binary image contain only 1 and 0 with variable name thresh. To find the upper limit and lower limit you could create a program with sliding bar(to find upper and lower limit in real time) or you could use program such as photsoshop to know what green color range value in HSV. U can search in google for more detail.

Comment: for pixel within range u set, it will value 1. And if not it will value 0. Image is a matrix

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete my comment in your question. One can use HSV/HLS colorspaces and use inRanges with the Hue channel. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# load image and threshold it
original = cv2.imread("a.jpg")
hsvframe = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsvframe, (160,40,40), (180, 255, 255))
mask = mask +  cv2.inRange(hsvframe, (0,40,40), (12, 255, 255)) # color red is at the beginning and end of the hue wheel

original[mask==255] = (0,255,0)
cv2.imshow("image", original)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Things to remember, Hue goes from 0-180 in np.uint8. This means if you need hue 300-360 the limits will be 150-180. The other two values are 0-255 where 255 = 100%.

The result of this small code is:

[image]

It is not perfect, but one can refine it using the methods suggested by the other answer. I hope this helps.